# How to control X11 windows grouping in R/tcltk

Tags: r, linux, tcl, x11, tk-toolkit

I am working on a GUI in R using tcltk and tcltk2 package. I have plenty of windows which are children of my main toplevel window called `base`.
I want the windows manager to treat all children as grouped under group leader base in order to get the launcher (ubuntu), and alt-switcher to show just one iconified version of my GUI (with a mark for each sub-window) instead of several different iconified windows.

This is a minimal example.  The key command is `tkwm.group` but I'm not being able to get a consistent outcome. Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. I don't really have a clue. If I don't destroy the window and source the script twice I kinda get the grouping but replicated windows and not exactly what I want.
Any help will be truly appreciated.

```
library(tcltk)
base <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(base,"Éccole!")

base$env$tw <- tktoplevel(base)

tkwm.group(base$env$tw)
```

Comment: I can confirm that running the script the first time does group the windows in the Ubuntu launcher and task switcher but running the script the second time or more (with or without closing and destroying the windows) does **not** group the windows anymore. If I restart the R session the grouping does work again with the same effect like above (1st time works, 2nd + more not). I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit and R 3.3.1 with RStudio. Did you already find a solution? Than please add an answer to your question to help others... Thx :-)

Comment: OK, some more observations: The usage of `tkwm.group` is not as intended. The second parameter must be used (see [http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M44]:
wm group window ?pathName? =>
# If pathName is specified, it gives the path name for the leader of a group of related windows.

Comment: In fact your example shows exactly the same behaviour without the `tkwm.group` command since it does only query the grouping state of `base$env$tw` and this sub windows does already belong to one group (`base`) since it was created with `tktoplevel(base)`. So the question to our **tcl/tk** experts is still: What is required to make window grouping working as expected?

Comment: Thank you very much for your for your comments. I still haven't found the answer but still looking...

Comment: Puh, until now I had only partial success by using `tkwm.transient(base$env$tw, base)` which at least hides the additional window icon of the second window - but the second window is not accessible anymore in the task switcher since "transient" means the second window is part of window 1. Not what you wanted but I document unsuccessful trials here too for other readers...